# Change Slider to automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this slider which changes on hover over bullet but I also want to change the slides automatically after an interval.
Here Is the code for the slider

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 var slide = $(".slide");
 var viewWidth = $(window).width();
 var sliderInner = $(".slider-inner");
 var childrenNo = sliderInner.children().length;

 sliderInner.width( viewWidth * childrenNo );

 $(window).resize(function(){
  viewWidth = $(window).width();
 });

 function setWidth(){
  slide.each(function(){
   $(this).width(viewWidth);
   $(this).css("left", viewWidth * $(this).index());
  }); 
 }

 function setActive(element){
  var clickedIndex = element.index();
  
  $(".slider-nav .active").removeClass("active");
  element.addClass("active");
  
  sliderInner.css("transform", "translateX(-" + clickedIndex * viewWidth + "px) translateZ(0)");
  
  $(".slider-inner .active").removeClass("active");
  $(".slider-inner .slide").eq(clickedIndex).addClass("active");
 }

 setWidth();

 $(".slider-nav > div").on("click", function(){
  setActive($(this));
 });

 $(window).resize(function(){
  setWidth();
 });

 setTimeout(function(){
  $(".slider").fadeIn(500);
 }, 2000);
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 9;
  padding: 40px;
  color: white;
}
.nav h1 {
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 3rem;
}
.nav .author {
  text-align: right;
}

.loading {
  background-color: #2ecc71;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 600px;
  line-height: 600px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

.slider {
  background-color: white;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: none;
}

.slider-inner {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.22, 1.61, 0.65, 1);
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.22, 1.61, 0.65, 1);
  -webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
    transition-duration: 1s;
  background-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition-delay: .75s;
    transition-delay: .75s;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
    transform: translateZ(0);
}

.slide {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #f1c40f;
  background-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.5, 0.25, 1.25);
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.5, 0.25, 1.25);
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0) scale(0.8, 0.8);
    transform: translateZ(0) scale(0.8, 0.8);
  -webkit-transition-duration: .5s;
    transition-duration: .5s;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 600px;
  font-size: 5rem;
  color: white;
}
.slide.active {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
    transform: scale(1, 1);
  -webkit-transition-delay: 2s;
    transition-delay: 2s;
}
.slide:nth-child(2n) {
  background-color: #2ecc71;
}
.slide:nth-child(3n) {
  background-color: #3498db;
}
.slide:nth-child(4n) {
  background-color: #9b50ba;
}

.slider-nav {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%);
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
.slider-nav > div {
  float: left;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  z-index: 2;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 50%;
  opacity: .5;
  -webkit-transition-duration: .25s;
    transition-duration: .25s;
  background-color: transparent;
}
.slider-nav > div:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
.slider-nav > div.active {
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transform: scale(2);
    transform: scale(2);
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<html >
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>Gummy slider</title>
      <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
   </head>
   <body>
      <nav class="nav">
         <h1> slider</h1>
         <p class="author">by Atishay Khare</p>
      </nav>
      <div class="loading">
         Loading...
      </div>
      <div class="slider">
         <div class="slider-inner">
            <div class="slide active">https://www.oxforduniversityimages.com/images/rotate/Image_Spring_17_7.gif</div>
            <div class="slide">2</div>
            <div class="slide">https://www.oxforduniversityimages.com/images/rotate/Image_Spring_17_7.gif</div>
            <div class="slide">https://www.oxforduniversityimages.com/images/rotate/Image_Spring_17_7.gif</div>
            <div class="slide">5</div>
            <div class="slide">6</div>
            <div class="slide">7</div>
            <div class="slide">8</div>
         </div>
         <nav class="slider-nav">
            <div class="active"></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
         </nav>
      </div>
      <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
      <script src="js/index.js"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

In here some error are also showing when i added it to snippet but it is working fine in my page i just need to make this silder to chnage silder automatically without click.

Comment: you probably need absolute image urls to make it work...

Comment: why so it is working fine I just need it to change automatically without the clicks

Comment: You need setInterval

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use following code within [`setInterval()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) method to automatically cycling an item:

```
var navs = $(".slider-nav > div");
var cur = $(".slider-nav > .active").index();
var nxt = (cur + 1) % navs.length;
setActive(navs.eq(nxt));
```

See full code in snippet below.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 var slide = $(".slide");
 var viewWidth = $(window).width();
 var sliderInner = $(".slider-inner");
 var childrenNo = sliderInner.children().length;

 sliderInner.width( viewWidth * childrenNo );

 $(window).resize(function(){
  viewWidth = $(window).width();
 });

 function setWidth(){
  slide.each(function(){
   $(this).width(viewWidth);
   $(this).css("left", viewWidth * $(this).index());
  }); 
 }

 function setActive(element){
  var clickedIndex = element.index();
  
  $(".slider-nav .active").removeClass("active");
  element.addClass("active");
  
  sliderInner.css("transform", "translateX(-" + clickedIndex * viewWidth + "px) translateZ(0)");
  
  $(".slider-inner .active").removeClass("active");
  $(".slider-inner .slide").eq(clickedIndex).addClass("active");
 }

 setWidth();

 $(".slider-nav > div").on("click", function(){
  setActive($(this));
 });

 $(window).resize(function(){
  setWidth();
 });

 setTimeout(function(){
  $(".slider").fadeIn(500);
 }, 2000);
  
  // Change Slider to automatically each 3 second.
  setInterval(function(){
    var navs = $(".slider-nav > div");
    var cur = $(".slider-nav > .active").index();
    var nxt = (cur + 1) % navs.length;
    console.log(nxt);
    setActive(navs.eq(nxt));
  }, 3000);
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 9;
  padding: 40px;
  color: white;
}
.nav h1 {
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 3rem;
}
.nav .author {
  text-align: right;
}

.loading {
  background-color: #2ecc71;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 600px;
  line-height: 600px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

.slider {
  background-color: white;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: none;
}

.slider-inner {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.22, 1.61, 0.65, 1);
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.22, 1.61, 0.65, 1);
  -webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
    transition-duration: 1s;
  background-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition-delay: .75s;
    transition-delay: .75s;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
    transform: translateZ(0);
}

.slide {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #f1c40f;
  background-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.5, 0.25, 1.25);
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.5, 0.25, 1.25);
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0) scale(0.8, 0.8);
    transform: translateZ(0) scale(0.8, 0.8);
  -webkit-transition-duration: .5s;
    transition-duration: .5s;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 600px;
  font-size: 5rem;
  color: white;
}
.slide.active {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
    transform: scale(1, 1);
  -webkit-transition-delay: 2s;
    transition-delay: 2s;
}
.slide:nth-child(2n) {
  background-color: #2ecc71;
}
.slide:nth-child(3n) {
  background-color: #3498db;
}
.slide:nth-child(4n) {
  background-color: #9b50ba;
}

.slider-nav {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%);
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
.slider-nav > div {
  float: left;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  z-index: 2;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 50%;
  opacity: .5;
  -webkit-transition-duration: .25s;
    transition-duration: .25s;
  background-color: transparent;
}
.slider-nav > div:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
.slider-nav > div.active {
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transform: scale(2);
    transform: scale(2);
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
      
<nav class="nav">
         <h1> slider</h1>
         <p class="author">by Atishay Khare</p>
      </nav>
      <div class="loading">
         Loading...
      </div>
      <div class="slider">
         <div class="slider-inner">
            <div class="slide active">https://www.oxforduniversityimages.com/images/rotate/Image_Spring_17_7.gif</div>
            <div class="slide">2</div>
            <div class="slide">https://www.oxforduniversityimages.com/images/rotate/Image_Spring_17_7.gif</div>
            <div class="slide">https://www.oxforduniversityimages.com/images/rotate/Image_Spring_17_7.gif</div>
            <div class="slide">5</div>
            <div class="slide">6</div>
            <div class="slide">7</div>
            <div class="slide">8</div>
         </div>
         <nav class="slider-nav">
            <div class="active"></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
         </nav>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set an interval. You can invoke automatically and reset with click event of a slide. Recall startAuto() to reset as there is a clearTnteval() added.

```
var Auto;

function startAuto() {
  clearInterval(Auto);    
  Auto = setInterval(function(){ 
    element = $(".middle-slider-nav .active").next();
    setActive(element);
  }, 3000);
}
```