# switching active div class in loop jquery

Tags: jquery

I have part of code

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="item active">item</div>
    <div class="item">item</div>
    <div class="item">item</div>
    <div class="item">item</div>
    <div class="item">item</div>
    <div class="item">item</div>
</div>
```

and i need to switch active class to next element after some delay and loop switching from last element to first. How i can do that ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change Slider to automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45524911/change-slider-to-automatically). The solution for your question is similar. Just change `.slider-nav` to `.container`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [setInterval(](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp)) method. To loop items use addition by modulus of items quantity. Run the snippet below to see result.

```js
var navs = $(".container > .item");
setInterval(function(){
  var cur = $(".container > .active").index();
  var nxt = (cur + 1) % navs.length;
  navs.eq(cur).removeClass("active");
  navs.eq(nxt).addClass("active");
}, 1000);
```

```css
.item {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: green;
}
.active {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="item active">item</div>
    <div class="item">item</div>
    <div class="item">item</div>
    <div class="item">item</div>
    <div class="item">item</div>
    <div class="item">item</div>
</div>
```